# Adding an additional row of HTML form inputs using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to dynamically add a new row of HTML form inputs (a new line which includes 6 inputs, namely, (Type(dropdown), Length, Width, Height, Weight and Quantity) into an existing "View" HTML form using Javascript. 
The current HTML form inputs are then accessed in my controller file via PHP $_POST requests. This works fine by retrieving the "name" field in the HTML form.
So, a user completes the first line, which id for the shipment of one parcel, and they want to add a second parcel, so, they click on an add(or remove) to add or remove an extra line of inputs.

I have the code working without adding the second row. If you leave the form at default, all the $variables are retrieved for the controller to act on them. 
I managed to get some Javascript code off the net which adds the second part of the input form correctly, but, I assumed the code would increment the "name" field so that the first shipment would be name=length and the second shipment would be name=length2. The code does need Bootstrap as well to work correctly.
I have PHP, HTML skills, but limited Javascript skills, hence my request please.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var counter = 0;

        $("#addrow").on("click", function() {
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";

            <!--cols += '<td><select class="form-control col-md-8" id="packaging_type" name="packaging_type' + counter + '"/></td>';-->

            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="length' + counter + '"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="width' + counter + '"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="height' + counter + '"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="weight' + counter + '"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity' + counter + '"/></td>';

            cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
            counter++;
        });

        $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            counter -= 1
        });

    });

    function calculateRow(row) {
        var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();

    }

    function calculateGrandTotal() {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function() {
            grandTotal += +$(this).val();
        });
        $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
    }
```

Ultimately, once I have clicked on the Add Row and entered all of the inputs, I would want the script to numerically increment the "name" input of the HTML form and then be able access them via PHP $_POST. 
If there is a better way of doing it, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: With your actual code, when you add a row, what are the names of the inputs in that new row ?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work anyway, I would suggest using a guid instead of a counter since deleting a row before the last would cause the counter to set itself to the same number as the current last row.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(3); 
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
      cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a script that with customisation appears that it will resolve my problem. I will post the outcome once completed so that it may help any future users. The script link is found at :- https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Duplicate-Input-Fields-jQuery-Repeatable/

Basically what this script does it it allows you to duplicate DIVs in a table or form, and increments the indexes, "name" "id" etc.
I will be using it to dynamically add additional "inputs" on a form.